# how to get record of a row in table whose corresponding button is clicked in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, for-loop, dom

I am working on Laravel project, I have some country information stored in database, using AJAX request I am retrieving record from database, and appending it in my HTML table, the rows(cells) of table are editable so, my main goal is to edit them and update them in database, issue I am facing is that, **I have added onClick event on update button, but it is automatically called when loop is in progress**, but when I click button **manually it doesn't work**, I want that relevant row record whose button is clicked so I can update it.

**demo screenshot**
[image]
**HTML code**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-md table-striped text-center" id="tblData">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">ID</th>
                <th class="text-center">Country Name</th>
                <th class="text-center">Region</th>
                <th class="text-center">Pressing Social Challenge</th>
                <th class="text-center">Ethnic Conflict</th>
                <th class="text-center">Civil Strife</th>
                <th class="text-center">Social Upheaval</th>
                <th class="text-center">Health Risk</th>
                <th class="text-center">SI SCORE</th>
                <th class="text-center">Update</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="mapDataRecord">

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**JS code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    load_data();

});


function load_data()
{
    getRecords='getRecords';
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: 
        {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url:"getMapData",
        method:"POST",
        data:'getRecords='+getRecords,
        success:function(data)
        {
            // $('#mapDataRecord').html(data);
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
            var dataAppend='';
            for (let index = 0; index < jsonData.length; index++) 
            {
                dataAppend+="<tr><td class='text-center font-weight-bold ids'>"+
                jsonData[index]['id']+"</td><td class='text-center font-weight-bold tester'>"+
                jsonData[index]['countryName']+"</td><td class='text-center font-weight-bold'>"+
                jsonData[index]['region']+"</td><td class='text-center' contenteditable>"+
                jsonData[index]['pressing_social_challenge']+"</td><td class='text-center' contenteditable>"+
                jsonData[index]['ethnic_conflict']+"</td><td class='text-center' contenteditable>"+
                jsonData[index]['civil_strife']+"</td><td class='text-center' contenteditable>"+
                jsonData[index]['social_upheaval']+"</td><td class='text-center' contenteditable>"+
                jsonData[index]['health_risk']+"</td><td class='text-center font-weight-bold'>"+
                getSiScore(jsonData[index])+"</td><td class='text-center'><button class='btn btn-primary' id='updateData' onclick='"+
                updateRecord(jsonData[index])+"'>Update</button></td></tr>";
            }
            $('#mapDataRecord').html(dataAppend);
            // console.log(jsonData[0]);
        }
    });
}

function getSiScore(array)
{
    var value = (array['pressing_social_challenge']*(10/100))+(array['ethnic_conflict']*(30/100))+(array['civil_strife']*(20/100))+(array['social_upheaval']*(20/100))+(array['health_risk']*(20/100));
    // return value;
    if(value>5)
    {
        return 5;
    }
    else
    {
        return value.toFixed(1);
    }
}

function updateRecord(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to put an alert to see if the data are ok.

you button id is always 'updateData' maybe there is a probleme with it, like you click on it and then javascript try to find the object with this id but as they are many it could just answer 'undefined'.

EDIT: you are calling updateRecord in your 'for' instead of putting the fonction inside the onClick , just take care of the quote and it should be OK

```
 for (let index = 0; index < jsonData.length; index++) 
            {
                dataAppend+="<tr><td class='text-center font-weight-bold ids'>"+
                jsonData[index]['id']+"</td><td class='text-center font-weight-bold tester'>"+
                jsonData[index]['countryName']+"</td><td class='text-center font-weight-bold'>"+
                jsonData[index]['region']+"</td><td class='text-center' contenteditable>"+
                jsonData[index]['pressing_social_challenge']+"</td><td class='text-center' contenteditable>"+
                jsonData[index]['ethnic_conflict']+"</td><td class='text-center' contenteditable>"+
                jsonData[index]['civil_strife']+"</td><td class='text-center' contenteditable>"+
                jsonData[index]['social_upheaval']+"</td><td class='text-center' contenteditable>"+
                jsonData[index]['health_risk']+"</td><td class='text-center font-weight-bold'>"+
                getSiScore(jsonData[index])+"</td><td class='text-center'><button class='btn btn-primary' id='updateData' onclick='updateRecord("+jsonData[index])+"'>Update</button></td></tr>";
            }
```

Should work

Comment: I am using, console to view the logs, problem is, in for loop, the function updateRecord is automatically called, I don't want this thing, I want to call the function only when update button is clicked

Comment: HAAA Then it's ez just keep the name of your function under quote. onclick='+
                updateRecord("+jsonData[index])+"'>Update</button></td></tr>";

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to sort out the issue by doing few changes on the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    load_data();

});

var jsonData = {};

function load_data()
{
    getRecords='getRecords';
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: 
        {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url:"getMapData",
        method:"POST",
        data:'getRecords='+getRecords,
        success:function(data)
        {
            // $('#mapDataRecord').html(data);
            jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
            var dataAppend='';
            for (let index = 0; index < jsonData.length; index++) 
            {
                dataAppend+="<tr><td class='text-center font-weight-bold ids'>"+
                jsonData[index]['id']+"</td><td class='text-center font-weight-bold tester'>"+
                jsonData[index]['countryName']+"</td><td class='text-center font-weight-bold'>"+
                jsonData[index]['region']+"</td><td class='text-center' contenteditable>"+
                jsonData[index]['pressing_social_challenge']+"</td><td class='text-center' contenteditable>"+
                jsonData[index]['ethnic_conflict']+"</td><td class='text-center' contenteditable>"+
                jsonData[index]['civil_strife']+"</td><td class='text-center' contenteditable>"+
                jsonData[index]['social_upheaval']+"</td><td class='text-center' contenteditable>"+
                jsonData[index]['health_risk']+"</td><td class='text-center font-weight-bold'>"+
                getSiScore(jsonData[index])+"</td><td class='text-center'><button class='btn btn-primary' id='updateData' data-index='"+ index + "'>Update</button></td></tr>";
            }
            $('#mapDataRecord').append($(dataAppend));
            // console.log(jsonData[0]);
        }
    });
}

function getSiScore(array)
{
    var value = (array['pressing_social_challenge']*(10/100))+(array['ethnic_conflict']*(30/100))+(array['civil_strife']*(20/100))+(array['social_upheaval']*(20/100))+(array['health_risk']*(20/100));
    // return value;
    if(value>5)
    {
        return 5;
    }
    else
    {
        return value.toFixed(1);
    }
}

function updateRecord(index){
    console.log(jsonData[Number(index)]);
}

$(document).on('click', "#updateData", function () {
    console.log(jsonData(Number($(this).attr("data-index"))));
});
```

1. Assigned jsonData variable outside if the function.
2. Replaced `$('#mapDataRecord').html(dataAppend);` with `$('#mapDataRecord').append($(dataAppend));`
3. changed `updateRecord` function.

**EDIT:**
Removed the click event from inside the for loop and added a common click event. You can apply same logic on your originally posted code.

Comment: problem is in the loop I think, that updateRecord function is auto called while the loop is displaying it in html, it should not be called automatically, you can write your own data in loop and append with html and test it

Comment: Please check i've edited my code and removed the click event from inside the for loop and added a common event out side of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

updateRecord function automatically runs because you are actually caling the function with this line `"updateRecord(jsonData[index])"`. To solve the issue you can add "index" as a data attribute to the button

```html
"<button data-index=" + index + ">Edit</button>"
```

then attach a listener to body element after the for loop and check the element is button and has a attribute called index. If it is then you can call the update function.

```js
document.body.onclick = function(event) {
   var index = event.target.getAttribute("index");
   if (index){
     updateRecord(jsonData[index]);
   }
```

Comment: If `index` is 0 then this will not call `updateRecord` since 0 is falsy... You may want to use `if (index != null) {` or `if (!isNaN(index)) {`. You'll also need to change your call to `getAttribute("data-index")`.